# Django CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. error

Tags: javascript, django, dropzone.js, django-csrf

I'm trying to upload an image using dropzone.js, but its not using login or register. I get `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

```js
Dropzone.options.fileDropzone = {
  url: '/media/',
  init: function() {
    this.on("error", function(file, message) {
      alert(message);
      this.removeFile(file);
    });
    var submitBtn = document.querySelector("#submitBtn");
    var myDropzone = this;
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("upload");

      myDropzone.processQueue();
    })
  },
  autoprocessQueue: true,
  clickable: true,
  thumbnailHeight: 90,
  thumbnailWidth: 115,
  maxFiles: 1,
  maxFilesize: 10,
  parallelUploads: 1,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  dictRemoveFile: 'delete',
  uploadMultiple: false,

}
```

```html
<form class="imageUploaderForm" method="post" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-title">Upload your Image</div>
  <div class="upload-type">File should be Jpeg, Png, Gif</div>
  <div class="dropzone" tabindex="0" class="drop-zone" style="border-style: dotted;" id="fileDropzone">

    <input accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" multiple="" type="file" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" name="myFile" class="drop-zone-input" style="display: none;">
    <div class="placeholder">
      <img class="hide" width="115" height="90" src="#" id="preview">

    </div>
  </div>
  <span style="color: rgb(169, 169, 169);">or</span>

</form>
```

and i used

`var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');`

and

`headers: { 'x-csrf-token': CSRF_TOKEN, },`

this two codes but it's still have same error

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```js
headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
}
```